# Can a semantic web Ontology have the same expressivity but a different profile?

Tags: semantic-web, ontology, owl, pellet

I'm analyzing some ontologies with the pellet reasoner, but I'm getting some strange results. When I perform the "pellet info" method on an ontology, and compare the OWL Profile to the DL Expressivity, I sometimes get ontologies that have different expressivities bu the same profile. That seems at least plausible, but then I am also finding ontologies with the same expressivity but different OWL Profiles. How is this possible, since the profile is a mark of the ontology's expressivity and reducibility in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

If you're considering comparing ontologies under OWL2 (based on [SROIQ](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~sattler/publications/sroiq-TR.pdf)) in general and, for example, a profile which is a sub-language such as OWL-EL (based on [EL++](http://lat.inf.tu-dresden.de/~clu/papers/archive/ijcai05.pdf)), then it is conceivable that an ontology can have the same expressivity and different 'profile', if you consider full OWL2 to be a 'profile' and *expressivity* to be DL-expressivity, since SROIQ subsumes EL++.

However, if by *profile* you strictly mean one of the three distinct [OWL2 profiles](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles); [OWL2-EL](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_EL), [OWL2-QL](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_QL) and [OWL2-RL](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_RL), then it is still possible that two ontologies with different OWL2 profiles can indeed have the same expressivity (at least, DL-expressivity) as these profiles are underpinned by description logics that may have *some* intersecting expressivity.

For example, ontologies in the OWL2-EL profile (based on [EL++](http://lat.inf.tu-dresden.de/~clu/papers/archive/ijcai05.pdf)) and in the OWL2-QL profile (based on [DL-Lite](http://www.springerlink.com/content/n17338715966v81h/fulltext.pdf)), both of these description logics can express things such as:

- Concept inclusion axioms
- Instance assertions against concepts and roles
- Existential property restrictions
- Conjunctive concept expressions

Ontologies in either profile (EL, QL) which are restricted to usage of the DL constructs which are common to both would therefore have the same DL-expressivity.